# PHP shell_exec, permission denied for executing -rwxrwxrwx shell script

Tags: php, permissions, shell-exec, poppler, pdf-to-html

I am currently over ssh on a remote CentOS 5.6 system which runs an Apache webserver. I need to use the poppler `pdftohtml` binary which, unfortunately, is not currently installed on that machine. So I downloaded the poppler package and built it under my user folder. Since I  I am not the system admin, I didn't do

```
make install
```

and I have all my compiled files under

```
/users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2/
```

The file that I need to execute through php `shell_exec()` is

```
/users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2/utils/pdftohtml
```

If I execute it through my ssh bash, I get the correct output. If I, instead, put this line on a php script:

```
echo shell_exec("/users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2/utils/pdftohtml");
```

I get the following output:

```
sh: /users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2/utils/pdftohtml: Permission denied
```

I tried setting to 777 the file permissions, which currently are -rwxrwxrwx. I also noticed that using `shell_exec("whoami");` results in "apache". Shouldn't apache be able to execute the script if the file permissions are -rwxrwxrwx?

I also know that installing poppler through `make install` would solve the problem but since this is for testing purpose, I would like to avoid "contaminating" the system outside my personal folder until the testing is complete.

Thanks to anyone who will help!

Comment: Doesn't CentOS also use SELinux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because a file is executable for a user does not mean that user is actually able to execute the file. The user needs to also be able to 'get to' the file: The user needs execution permission for all 'parent directories', in your case for /users, myfolder, poppler-0.18.2 and utils.

Assuming /users is the same basic thing as /home, everybody should have +x on that. From there, you can set it: simply do `chmod o+x /users/myfolder /users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2 /users/myfolder/poppler-0.18.2/utils`

(Note: This will make it possible for **everybody** to execute this binary, not just Apache.)

If the apache user and you share a group, it would be better to use chown the poppler directory and everything in to be owned by that group, and set g+x instead of o+x.

Comment: damn it, it's crazy. two days of investigations wasted( thanks a lot. I saw a couple of similar answers here but they did not mention that ALL parents directories must have execute permissions. Only this worked for me.