# shell_exec() - Error when executing php script

Tags: php, shell-exec

When I'm trying to execute a PHP script using `shell_exec()`, it's not working.

In the error_log file it shows:

> PHP Warning:  shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Unable to execute
>   'php /home/snabbsam/public_html/.....

**System**
Centos

**shell_exec works with clamscan**
`shell_exec()` works on `clamscan()` function of clamav.
But it's not executing PHP script

**Things I've checked:**

- PHP `safe_mode` is off
- `shell_exec()` is not present in `disable_functions` in php.ini
- Tried giving executable permission to the file & the parent folders as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668666/402089

Comment: Have you tried adding a full path to the php executable? I doubt it'll make a difference, but it certainly can't hurt.

Comment: intitially i used $seoutput = shell_exec('php /home/...'); After your suggestion, I used $seoutput = shell_exec('/usr/local/lib/php /home/s..'); Now there's no entry in error_log, $seoutput is blank & there's no output. Also the target script is not getting executed

Comment: No, I meant adding the path to where `php` can be found.

Comment: php.ini is present in "/usr/local/lib/php.ini". So I gave the path to PHP as "/usr/local/lib/php". Isn't this the way?

Comment: You'll need to find the php executable, not the config file

Comment: wow. thanks bro. the php file was actually at "/usr/local/bin". When i used $seoutput = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php /home/s..'); it worked. thanks a lot bro. Please put this as an answer. I'll mark it

Comment: Huh. You'd've thought that PHP would know where its own executable was. The mysteries of file permissions and environment variables are clearly too complex for me before my second coffee of the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a full path to where the executable for `php` is in your `shell_exec` call, just in case it's in a directory that's not accessible by default for the webserver user.

Comment: To get path to the php executable use "which php" command as mentioned in http://serverfault.com/a/58388